# Editar registros sql sobre tabla

Tags: php, sql-server

tengo el siguiente código en el cual hago una consulta y la reflejo en una tabla.

código:

cabeza tabla:

```
  <table role="grid"><colgroup><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col style="width:40px"><col style="width:40px"><col style="width:40px"><col style="width:40px"><col style="width:40px"><col style="width:40px"><col></colgroup><thead class="k-grid-header" role="rowgroup" style="width: 1770px;"><tr role="row"><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="Maquina" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="Maquina" data-index="0" id="5b910a71-8dc7-4695-b9a5-7c6f43f0c784" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter" data-dir="asc" aria-sort="ascending"><a class="k-link" href="#"><span class="k-icon k-i-sort-asc-sm"></span></a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="Maquina" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="Maquina" data-index="0" id="5b910a71-8dc7-4695-b9a5-7c6f43f0c784" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter" data-dir="asc" aria-sort="ascending"><a class="k-link" href="#">Fecha Fab.<span class="k-icon k-i-sort-asc-sm"></span></a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="NOF" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="OF" data-index="1" id="4212c109-8b9a-4996-89ca-be2a73b5cdf1" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">Máquina</a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="ClienteNombre" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="CLIENTE" data-index="1" id="15b6ce43-2413-40f6-9230-95dd4593dfe7" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">Cliente</a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="NOF" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="OF" data-index="1" id="4212c109-8b9a-4996-89ca-be2a73b5cdf1" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">Orden</a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="NOF" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="OF" data-index="1" id="4212c109-8b9a-4996-89ca-be2a73b5cdf1" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">Linea</a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="NOF" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="OF" data-index="1" id="4212c109-8b9a-4996-89ca-be2a73b5cdf1" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">Cod.Artículo</a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="NOF" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="OF" data-index="1" id="4212c109-8b9a-4996-89ca-be2a73b5cdf1" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">Descrip.</a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="NOF" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="OF" data-index="1" id="4212c109-8b9a-4996-89ca-be2a73b5cdf1" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">Cantidad</a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="NOF" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="OF" data-index="1" id="4212c109-8b9a-4996-89ca-be2a73b5cdf1" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">Metros</a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="NOF" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="OF" data-index="1" id="4212c109-8b9a-4996-89ca-be2a73b5cdf1" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">Material 1</a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="NOF" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="OF" data-index="1" id="4212c109-8b9a-4996-89ca-be2a73b5cdf1" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">Material 2</a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="NOF" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="OF" data-index="1" id="4212c109-8b9a-4996-89ca-be2a73b5cdf1" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">Ancho</a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="Linea" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="Linea" data-index="2" id="5ea2eacb-b006-4f73-8e1b-6a557a718f74" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">Magnético</a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="Cliente" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="Cliente" data-index="3" id="20b160ee-fbbb-4a72-8e26-45f1ef25b43a" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">Troq.</a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="Articulo" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="Articulo" data-index="4" id="ae93e6f6-f6dd-4554-8275-3ebe65cdde6d" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">Nº Colores</a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="NOF" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="OF" data-index="1" id="4212c109-8b9a-4996-89ca-be2a73b5cdf1" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">C1</a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="NOF" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="OF" data-index="1" id="4212c109-8b9a-4996-89ca-be2a73b5cdf1" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">C2</a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="NOF" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="OF" data-index="1" id="4212c109-8b9a-4996-89ca-be2a73b5cdf1" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">C3</a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="NOF" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="OF" data-index="1" id="4212c109-8b9a-4996-89ca-be2a73b5cdf1" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">C4</a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="NOF" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="OF" data-index="1" id="4212c109-8b9a-4996-89ca-be2a73b5cdf1" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">C5</a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="NOF" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="OF" data-index="1" id="4212c109-8b9a-4996-89ca-be2a73b5cdf1" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">C6</a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="NOF" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="OF" data-index="1" id="4212c109-8b9a-4996-89ca-be2a73b5cdf1" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">C7</a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="NOF" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="OF" data-index="1" id="4212c109-8b9a-4996-89ca-be2a73b5cdf1" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">C8</a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="FSalida" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="FSalida" data-index="13" id="16e97ba6-fc9b-4558-9f38-42b6b4e201eb" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">Tiempo</a></th><th scope="col" role="columnheader" data-field="FEntrega" aria-haspopup="true" rowspan="1" data-title="FEntrega" data-index="14" id="c28a3f33-d4e9-4110-a02d-310de9a51509" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">Estado</a></th></thead>
```

consulta y datos en tabla

```
 <?php

// Obtenemos los datos la máquina 41
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ESTADO=isnull(VEstadoGoitek.OF_Estado_Dsc, 'Sin Procesar'), Orden=isnull(OF_OrdenOFs, '999'), Mag= convert (numeric,OF_Magnetico) ,OF_Magnetico,Tec_Tip_stamp,OF_OrdenOFs,Maquina,Tec_Ava_stamp, Linea=VTiempos.of_lin, Tec_codigo, Fecha=convert(varchar(10), FFAB, 103),Metros=  convert (numeric,OF_MT_Tirada),Cant= convert( dec(10), OF_Cantidad), Clie_nombre,  OF_Descripcion, OF_Cod_Art, OF_Cantidad,OF_MT_Tirada, Ordenes.OF_Tipo_Papel , OF_Cod_Troq, Ordenes.OF_Num_Tintas, OF_Color1, OF_Color2, OF_Color3, OF_Color4, OF_Color5, OF_Color6, OF_Color7, N_Orden=Vtiempos.Of_n_orden, OF_Color8, of_estado_dsc, tIMER=CONVERT(char(5), DATEADD(MINUTE, Tiempo, ''), 114)

FROM VEstadoGoitek RIGHT JOIN (((Ordenes INNER JOIN ARTITTEC ON Ordenes.OF_Cod_Art = ARTITTEC.Tec_codigo) INNER JOIN VCLIENTE ON Ordenes.OF_Cod_Cli = VCLIENTE.Clie_codigo) INNER JOIN VTiempos ON (VTiempos.of_lin = Ordenes.OF_Lin) AND (Ordenes.OF_N_Orden = VTiempos.Of_n_orden)) ON VEstadoGoitek.OF_N_Orden = VTiempos.Of_n_orden and VTiempos.of_lin=VEstadoGoitek.of_lin 
where  FFAB >= getdate()-2 and FFAB < getdate() +2 AND  Clie_emp = 1 AND Maquina = '41'
ORDER BY Orden asc, Fecha asc, ESTADO asc";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if ($stmt === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// Guardamos los datos de todas las máquinas 41 en el array $maquinas
$maquinas = array();
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
 $maquina = array();
             $maquina['OF_Magnetico']=$row['OF_Magnetico'];
             $maquina['Fecha']=$row['Fecha'];
             $maquina['Maquina']=$row['Maquina'];
             $maquina['Clie_nombre']=$row['Clie_nombre']; 
            $maquina['N_Orden']=$row['N_Orden'];
             $maquina['Linea']=$row['Linea']; 
            $maquina['OF_Cod_Art']=$row['OF_Cod_Art']; 
            $maquina['OF_Descripcion']=$row['OF_Descripcion']; 
            $maquina['Cant']=$row['Cant'];
            $maquina['Metros']=$row['Metros'];
             $maquina['OF_Tipo_Papel']=$row['OF_Tipo_Papel'];
        $maquina['Tec_Tip_stamp']=$row['Tec_Tip_stamp']; 
       $maquina['Tec_Ava_stamp']=$row['Tec_Ava_stamp'];

         $maquina['Mag']=$row['Mag'];  

             $maquina['OF_Cod_Troq']=$row['OF_Cod_Troq']; 
             $maquina['OF_Num_Tintas']=$row['OF_Num_Tintas']; 

             $maquina['OF_Color2']=$row['OF_Color2']; 
            $maquina['OF_Color3']=$row['OF_Color3']; 
             $maquina['OF_Color4']=$row['OF_Color4']; 
             $maquina['OF_Color5']=$row['OF_Color5']; 
          $maquina['OF_Color6']=$row['OF_Color6']; 
             $maquina['OF_Color7']=$row['OF_Color7']; 
            $maquina['OF_Color8']=$row['OF_Color8'];
            $maquina['tIMER']=$row['tIMER'];
          $maquina['ESTADO']=$row['ESTADO'];
$maquina['OF_Color1']=$row['OF_Color1'];
$maquina['Orden']=$row['Orden'];
```

Para esta máquina en particular, buscamos si hay otras máquinas con el mismo CodP que no sean la máquina 41

```
 $sql2 ="SELECT DISTINCT ESTADO=isnull(VEstadoGoitek.OF_Estado_Dsc, 'Sin Procesar'), Orden=isnull(OF_OrdenOFs, '999'), Mag= convert (numeric,OF_Magnetico) ,OF_Magnetico,Tec_Tip_stamp,OF_OrdenOFs,Maquina,Tec_Ava_stamp, Linea=VTiempos.of_lin, Tec_codigo, Fecha=convert(varchar(10), FFAB, 103),Metros=  convert (numeric,OF_MT_Tirada),Cant= convert( dec(10), OF_Cantidad), Clie_nombre,  OF_Descripcion, OF_Cod_Art, OF_Cantidad,OF_MT_Tirada, Ordenes.OF_Tipo_Papel , OF_Cod_Troq, Ordenes.OF_Num_Tintas, OF_Color1, OF_Color2, OF_Color3, OF_Color4, OF_Color5, OF_Color6, OF_Color7, N_Orden=Vtiempos.Of_n_orden, OF_Color8, of_estado_dsc, tIMER=CONVERT(char(5), DATEADD(MINUTE, Tiempo, ''), 114)

FROM VEstadoGoitek RIGHT JOIN (((Ordenes INNER JOIN ARTITTEC ON Ordenes.OF_Cod_Art = ARTITTEC.Tec_codigo) INNER JOIN VCLIENTE ON Ordenes.OF_Cod_Cli = VCLIENTE.Clie_codigo) INNER JOIN VTiempos ON (VTiempos.of_lin = Ordenes.OF_Lin) AND (Ordenes.OF_N_Orden = VTiempos.Of_n_orden)) ON VEstadoGoitek.OF_N_Orden = VTiempos.Of_n_orden and VTiempos.of_lin=VEstadoGoitek.of_lin 
where  FFAB >= getdate()-2 and FFAB < getdate() +2 AND  Clie_emp = 1 AND (Maquina = '42' or Maquina= '43') AND OF_Magnetico= " . $maquina['OF_Magnetico'];
$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
$stmt2 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql2 , $params, $options );

$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt2);


    if ($stmt2 === false) {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));


    }





    if (sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt2) > 0) {
        $maquina['repetido'] = true;
    } else {
        $maquina['repetido'] = false;
    }

    $maquinas[] = $maquina;
}

    ?>
```

En el tercer  hacemos la comprobación de que, si existe una máquina repetida, lo pinte en rojo

```
<tbody role="rowgroup"><tr data-uid="0bc4355b-a2b7-4cf6-9701-192e77ce6d1d" role="row">

    <?php foreach ($maquinas as $maquina): ?>
        <?php 
$cadena2 = $maquina['OF_Color1'];
$cadena = $maquina['Orden'];
$resultado = str_replace("999", " ", $cadena);
$resultado2 = str_replace("BLACK C", "BLACK ", $cadena2);
?>
            <td role="gridcell"><span style="color: #ff0000"><strong><?php echo $resultado ?></strong></span></td> 
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['Fecha'];?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['Maquina'];?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo utf8_encode ($maquina['Clie_nombre']);?></td>
            <td role="gridcell" ><?php echo $maquina['N_Orden']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell" ><?php echo $maquina['Linea']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell" > <a target="_blank" href="https://clientes.ealbeniz.com/clientes/images/<?php echo $maquina['OF_Cod_Art'];?>.pdf"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Cod_Art']; ?></a></td>
            <td role="gridcell" ><?php echo utf8_encode( $maquina['OF_Descripcion']); ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['Cant'];?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['Metros']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell" ><?php echo $maquina['OF_Tipo_Papel'];?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['Tec_Tip_stamp']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell" ><?php echo $maquina['Tec_Ava_stamp'];?></td>
           <td role="gridcell" <?php echo ($maquina['repetido']) ? 'style="color: red; font-weight: bold;"' : ''; ?>><?php echo $maquina['Mag']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Cod_Troq']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Num_Tintas'];?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $resultado2 ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color2'];?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color3']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color4']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color5']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color6']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color7'];?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color8']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['tIMER']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['ESTADO'];?></td>
        </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </b>
        </font>

<?php



?>





 </tbody>
</table><div class="k-pager-wrap k-grid-pager k-widget k-floatwrap" data-role="pager"><span class="k-pager-info k-label"></span></div></div>
```

La tabla quedaría como la imagen:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría poder editar sobre la tabla, el campo **Orden** Es decir. ejemplo: si un registro tiene el número 1 en el campo orden, poder borrarselo desde la tabla y ponerselo a otro de los registros que aparecen....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías agregar un evento al td que contiene ese `onclick` y al seleccionar con jquery reemplazarlo con un input. Una vez que te salis de ese input `onblur`, que se haga la actualización a la base de datos.

Es mas podes hacer aparecer un modal, o un prompt o lo que necesites en el evento `onclick`

Comment: ¿Podrías ponerme algún ejemplo de código? No domino mucho esté tema. Gracias :)